# HQL and Hibernate Criteria with Having and GROUP BY clause

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have Problem when I executing the following Hibernate HQL Query:

```
String hql = "from ProcessInstanceHistory where processInstance.processInstanceId=122 group by newStatusId having max(processModifiedDate)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

List qResult = query.list();
ProcessInstanceHistory processInstanceHistory = (ProcessInstanceHistory) qResult.get(0);
```

It gives me Following error when I run above script without `HAVING` clause:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at Test.main(Test.java:140)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 'tne_travel_7_4_1.processins0_.PI_HISTORY_ID' isn't in GROUP BY
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3515)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1761)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1912)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 8 more
```

And when I use `HAVING` clause it gives:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: max near line 1, column 117 [from tne.nexstep.dao.ProcessInstanceHistory where processInstance.processInstanceId=122 group by newStatusId having max(processModifiedDate)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    at Test.main(Test.java:138)
```

I had also try with Hibernate Criteria but it won't work.

Is their any other way to acheive the same task ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Your `having` clause is incomplete. It needs to be a condition e.g. `having max(processModifiedDate) > 1`. Also, you need to project using aggregate functions and if you need to project on certain columns, they need to be in the group by. Currently, all columns(fields) in the `ProcessInstanceHistory` class are in the projection.
e.g.,

```
String hql = "Select newStatusId, max(processModifiedDate) from ProcessInstanceHistory where processInstance.processInstanceId=122 group by newStatusId having max(processModifiedDate) > 1";
```

More information on the **HAVING** clause can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp.

Comment: But processModifiedDate is actual a date , I am trying to Fetch record which is latest updated by date so it won't need a condition . actually above query in SQL works properly . but when I try with Java it gives Problem ...... And before that When I try with group by it shows error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 'tne_travel_7_4_1.processins0_.PI_HISTORY_ID' isn't in GROUP BY , Thanks for your reply

Comment: I think you need to get the `max(processModifiedDate)` for `processInstance.processInstanceId=122` first and than select records from ProcessInstanceHistory with this date. You are getting the `'tne_travel_7_4_1.processins0_.PI_HISTORY_ID' isn't in GROUP BY` error because you are selecting all columns from `ProcessInstanceHistory` and PI_HISTORY_ID is the first. As I mentioned before, only columns present in the group by clause can be used in the select of a group by query.